# Binding a dropdown on the onblur event of a textbox using jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a textbox whose value when passed to sp should return a list. I have to bind this list to Dropdown using jQuery Ajax. I have written the sp but my problem is how to bind the dropdown depending on value of textbox in the onblur event of Textbox.

Kindly help. And please excuse for typing errors if any.

Comment: Are you able to post the code you've got so far?

Comment: I had done the same using Update Panel, but now I have been asked to do with jQuery and I have no idea of it..:(

Comment: Hello r u there u got the answer

Comment: Yess..it worked..thanku so much..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#txtboxid').focusout(function () {
          var yourvalue = $('#textboxid').val();
          $.post("/your/url", { Parametername : yourvalue }, function (result) {
              $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                   $('#dropdownid').append($("<option></option>").html(value).val(value)); 
                   // Dropdown Binding
              });
          }, "json");
      });
   });
```

Note : Parameter must be same as your controller for example public void data(string nval) means your parameter name also nval

Comment: But I guess, I will have to pass the textboxid value as a parameter to the sp which will return a list?

Comment: u need to pass textbox id or text box value

Comment: Are you getting or not

Comment: No need any jquery Libraries friend just copy paste this code put ur url in post method then change parametername its working

Comment: ya wecome friend  r u using this in mvc application

Comment: No...asp.net...not mvc

Answer (score 2):

i have done similar in my project.

$( "#target" ).blur(function() {
                  alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: '../GetRolesAndPriviledgeServlet?filepath='+path+'&type='+type,
                        type: 'post',
                        success:function(response){
                            obj = JSON.parse(response);                          

                            $('#DropDownListAssigned').empty(); 

                            for (var i=0; i <obj.length ; i++)
                            {                                               

                                    var oSelField = document.getElementById("DropDownListAssigned");
                                    var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
                                    oOption.text = obj[i+1];
                                    oOption.value = obj[i+1];                   
                                    oSelField.options.add(oOption);                                     
                            }
                        },                      
                        error:function(){
                        }
                    }); 

    });
```